# intersection of numbers on wolfram

Tags: riemann-zeta, wolfram-alpha, intersection-theory

After evaluations of the Riemann Hypothesis, with reflective thoughts over a year as to how to solve it, a formula that is very close has been found, if not distinctly the act of the original proof, with a different formula. The Riemann Zeta function is a technically perfect example of counting primes.

Here, I have linked the application of my formula to Wolfram Alpha.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28Re%28zeta%285%2F3t+i%29+-+Re%28zeta%281+%2B+152%2F9t+i%29%29++%2B++i%29%29+from+t+%3D+1000+to+1010

Since I cannot find how to do an intersection of primes and my numbers, I cannot tell how many I have or I am missing. That is the nature of my question. How do I know, or how can I find the answer I need to?

Comment: It is spelled Riemann, and this question is not suitable for this site.

Comment: @wjm I was afraid of that. Do you have any places I could go?

Comment: This question would be suitable for this site if you clarified the mathematical points that you want help with.

Comment: @RobArthan Okay. I am only wondering how to find out if I'm right without hand checking a 1,000 prime numbers. Does anyone know a C++ library with the ability?I will google that.

Comment: What do you need to check about these 1,000 numbers?

Comment: @RobArthan I have to make sure I crossed the x axis on each of them

Comment: Well that's not really feasible if you are using floating point arithmetic for your calculations.

Comment: @RobArthan In the original equation, Riemann is able to find them within a 0.5 offset

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: @RobArthan I just wanted to see if anyone knew a fast way to see, as if there were any websites, or anything particular to the Riemann Zeta and Millenium Prize Competition that would help me assert my proposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/riemann_zeta

I (or you) can figure out what to do with this function, in C++.